# OAUTH redirect URI can't figure out how to use in Android Mobile App

Tags: android, redirect, oauth, oauth-2.0, fitbit

I'm writing an Android app that integrates with Fitbit and Jawbone.

I've already completed the Jawbone integration.  Jawbone uses OAUTH2 and they provide a default redirect URI of http://localhost/helloup?

This is probably me not fully understanding OAUTH but I was under the impression that the redirect URI was used for processing the reply from the server.

In a mobile app this really doesn't make any sense to me.  I just want to POST to a server and get an accesstoken that I can use.

Can someone please explain to me the following:

1. What is the elementary school explanation of what the OAUTH redirect URI is used for?
2. In a mobile app like Android how does the redirect URI factor in?

I'm happy to elaborate on my question if what I'm asking is not clear enough.

Cheers